# copy and paste a string block to JS code

Tags: javascript, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create multiline strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/how-to-create-multiline-strings)

is it a way to assign following text to a variable more easily:

```
line 1
line 2 
line 3
```

instead of:

```
 t="line 1\nline 2\nline 3";
```

I want copy and paste some text to test some RexExt on it without modifying every ones.

Comment: Why not paste it in a textarea and grab the value? Alternatively wrap in a div

Comment: @mplungjan I need preserve \n \t ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may [try this site](http://www.htmlescape.net/stringescape_tool.html). Not automatic but pretty faster than manual